# Smtp2go Username's account not allowed to send

Tags: python, django, smtp

I seem to be unable to send an email via my smtp server that is integrated with Django. I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/smtp2go-oss/smtp2go-django/

Error keeps saying that the smtp's username is not allowed to send.

I have checked my login password and username in `settings.py` and with my API key exported. So what am I doing wrong here?

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 12, 2018 - 07:36:23
Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'ChatBotWebApp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
ERROR:smtp2go.core:['Message failed - Error: {\'weiyuxin100@gmail.com\': (550, b"that smtp username\'s account is not allowed to send")}']
INFO:smtp2go.core:Success? False
INFO:smtp2go.core:Status Code: 200
INFO:smtp2go.core:Request ID: a2679416-fde0-11e8-b8ef-f23c917b36ad
```

Would appreciate any help here, thanks!

Comment: I'm with the same problem. But im trying to send through my gmail as a custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

your smtp account service not allow you send emails or your email limit expire from your smtp account service provider.

Comment: I have a limit of 1000 emails this month, so it might be the former case that you've said. I've checked all settings of my smtp account (smtp2go) to ensure that emails can be sent and none are blocked. Any hope?